# Android 7.1.1 SSLHandShakeException Connection Closed by Peer

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, x509certificate

First, I've already searched the internet and have been debugging for 3 days.

This is the exact error,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:197)
  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
  at com.aws.wiremo.common.CommonFunctions.sendRequestEx(CommonFunctions.java:618)
  at com.aws.wiremo.common.CommonFunctions.sendRequest(CommonFunctions.java:556)
  at com.aws.wiremo.screen.kdo.LoadingScreen$MakeRequest.doInBackground(LoadingScreen.java:146)
  at com.aws.wiremo.screen.kdo.LoadingScreen$MakeRequest.doInBackground(LoadingScreen.java:125)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Due to confidentiality reasons, I can't post the codes.
There's no caused by exception given by the StackTrace so i can't really diagnose the problem. 


Here are some information I can share.

- Application is working in Android 5.0.2.
- Request is being sent to https://[IP_address]:443/
- I am sending a request to a special hardware, like a control box. I can only write and retrieve data through POST requests.
- The certificate chain that I receive in my CustomTrustManager's checkServerTrusted method has a CN that is not an IP address and not a DNS, more like a word only (i.e. CN=commonname).
- My HostNameVerifier is ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER temporarily (which i think might solve the problem with the 3rd info?).
- I am using a DummyTrustManager that trusts all certificates.
- I am using SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").
- The certificate being used is self-signed.
- The certificate used by the hardware uses AES128 cipher.
- Can successfully send request to another URL that uses a self-signed certificate with TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher.

Any inputs or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the server you're connecting to require a client certificate? And if so, do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I have one. I tried implementing a trust manager that trusts that certificate and it is working in Android 5.0.2 but it is not working in 7.1.1.

Comment: I recommend to check the capabilities of the hardware you are connecting to. Maybe it is still using SSLv3  - and it might be that Android7 does not support SSLv3 anymore or that it is disabled by default, similar to many modern systems.

Comment: Okay. WIll do. thanks.

Comment: Does the server trust your client certificate?

Comment: That's where I'm not sure. I just generated the certificate from the chain variable in the checkServerTrusted method of my custom trust manager.

Comment: What you do in the client about the server's certificate is irrelevant to whether the server trusts the client's certificate. If the client certificate is self-signed, it won't be trusted unless you've imported it into the server's truststore, and if the server doesn't trust it the client can't even send it, so if the server requires it and doesn't get it, it is free to close the connection.

Comment: But why is it working in Android 5.0.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was that the Keys generated by my Custom Provider's KeyPairGenerator is not working anymore in Android 7 even though it's working in Android 5. I tried changing my KeyPairGenerator Provider to BouncyCastle (BC) and it worked again.

I tried searching the internet for the reason for this but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I hope this answer can help somebody.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Just change the provider.